# There's an excess property with my sql to json code file

Tags: php, sql

guys help me I'm a bit confused how my code producing an extra property to my json result see below:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "thecmlco_widget"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM widgetdb";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$rows = array();

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }
    echo json_encode($rows);
    mysqli_close($connect);
```

here is the result with an extra property 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5 and I don't know why its creating those extra property.

```
[
  {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "Vacation",
    "2": "http://trilogy.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/dm-theme-1000772-en-291",
    "3": "https://dd-cdn.multiscreensite.com/themes-panel/preview/vacation.jpg",
    "4": "1000772",
    "5": "0",
    "id": "1",
    "template_name": "Vacation",
    "preview_url": "http://trilogy.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/dm-theme-1000772-en-291",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://dd-cdn.multiscreensite.com/themes-panel/preview/vacation.jpg",
    "templade_id": "1000772",
    "can_build_from_url": "0"
  },
  {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "Product",
    "2": "https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/ce1f372c/siteTemplateIcons/Mstzqt8GTRSxzCt6QTue_BigPreview_iotech.png",
    "3": "https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/ce1f372c/siteTemplateIcons/Mstzqt8GTRSxzCt6QTue_BigPreview_iotech.png",
    "4": "1003040",
    "5": "0",
    "id": "2",
    "template_name": "Product",
    "preview_url": "https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/ce1f372c/siteTemplateIcons/Mstzqt8GTRSxzCt6QTue_BigPreview_iotech.png",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/ce1f372c/siteTemplateIcons/Mstzqt8GTRSxzCt6QTue_BigPreview_iotech.png",
    "templade_id": "1003040",
    "can_build_from_url": "0"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` function to get rows as associative array

Comment: thank you! it works .. will accept this as an answer after 6 mins okay thanks @peter